Hook is not reliably updating data it randomly works
I have a hook to keep track of whether a button was clicked. These buttons can be selected with isSelected from the beginning so I have an initialTags variable to track the intial state of the tag. I have an addFactiiis variables that tells the server to add or update data and a removeFactiiiIds variable that tells the server to delete factiiis with that id. This entire thing does not work reliably. I've tried useState and other ways to implement this and nothing works reliably. I use the Here is the hook:
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { FactiiiTag } from "../domain/factiiis/factiiis";
import { compareTags } from "../helpers/compareTags";

const useFactiiis = () => {
  // const [initialTags, setInitialTags] = useState<FactiiiTag[]>([]);
  //   const [addFactiiis, setAddFactiiis] = useState<FactiiiTag[]>([]);
  //   const [removeFactiiiIds, setRemoveFactiiiIds] = useState<number[]>([]);
  let initialTags: FactiiiTag[] = [];
  let addFactiiis: FactiiiTag[] = [];
  let removeFactiiiIds: number[] = [];

  const updateAddFactiiis = useCallback(
    (tag: FactiiiTag, updatedTag: FactiiiTag) => {
      if (!initialTags.find((ft) => ft.id === tag.id)) {
        initialTags.push(tag);
      }

      const initialTag = initialTags.find((ft) => ft.id === tag.id);

      if (!initialTag) {
        //WARNING: This should never happen
        alert("Initial tag not found");
        return;
      }

      if (updatedTag.isSelected) {
        //tag switching to selected
        if (compareTags(initialTag, updatedTag)) {
          //tag did not change, do nothing
          //   setAddFactiiis((prev) => prev.filter((ft) => ft.id !== tag.id));
          //   setRemoveFactiiiIds((prev) => prev.filter((id) => id !== id));
          addFactiiis = addFactiiis.filter((ft) => ft.id !== tag.id);
          removeFactiiiIds = removeFactiiiIds.filter((id) => id !== id);
        } else {
          //tag changed, update
          //   setAddFactiiis((prev) => [...prev, updatedTag]);
          //   setRemoveFactiiiIds((prev) => prev.filter((id) => id !== id));
          addFactiiis.push(updatedTag);
          removeFactiiiIds = removeFactiiiIds.filter((id) => id !== id);
        }
      } else {
        //tag switching to unselected
        if (initialTag.isSelected) {
          //tag was selected, remove
          //   setAddFactiiis((prev) => prev.filter((ft) => ft.id !== tag.id));
          //   setRemoveFactiiiIds((prev) => [...prev, updatedTag.id]);
          addFactiiis = addFactiiis.filter((ft) => ft.id !== tag.id);
          removeFactiiiIds.push(updatedTag.id);
        } else {
          //tag was unselected, do nothing
          //   setAddFactiiis((prev) => prev.filter((ft) => ft.id !== tag.id));
          //   setRemoveFactiiiIds((prev) => prev.filter((id) => id !== id));
          addFactiiis = addFactiiis.filter((ft) => ft.id !== tag.id);
          removeFactiiiIds = removeFactiiiIds.filter((id) => id !== id);
        }
      }
      console.log(
        "initialTags: ",
        initialTags.map((ft) => ({
          name: ft.name,
          isSelected: ft.isSelected,
        })),
      );
      console.log(
        "addFactiiis: ",
        addFactiiis.map((ft) => ({
          name: ft.name,
          isSelected: ft.isSelected,
        })),
      );

      console.log("removeFactiiiIds: ", removeFactiiiIds);
    },
    [addFactiiis, removeFactiiiIds],
  );

  const clearFactiiis = () => {
    console.log("clearing factiiis");
    addFactiiis = [];
    removeFactiiiIds = [];
    // setAddFactiiis([]);
    // setRemoveFactiiiIds([]);
    initialTags.length = 0;
  };

  return {
    addFactiiis,
    removeFactiiiIds,
    updateAddFactiiis,
    clearFactiiis,
  };
};

export default useFactiiis;

Here is how I call it in. Take note the addFactiiis does not update despite being pulled from the hook.
const FactiiiModal = (props: Props) => {
  const { addFactiiis, removeFactiiiIds, updateAddFactiiis, clearFactiiis } =
    useProcessFactiiis();

  const submitHandler = async () => {
    try {
      setButtonLoading(true);

      await tagPost(
        props.post.id,
        addFactiiis.map((ft) => ({
          factiiiId: ft.id,
          data: ft.postFactiii.data,
          spaceTimes: ft.postFactiii.spaceTimes,
          uploads: ft.postFactiii.uploads,
          anonymous,
        })),
        removeFactiiiIds,
      );
    } catch (error) {
      Toast.show({
        type: "error",
        text1: "Couldn't tag post",
        text2:
          "Something went wrong while tagging the post, please try again later.",
      });
      props.closeHandler();
    } finally {
      setButtonLoading(false);
    }
  };
}

Here is another place where processAddFactiii gets called. The process function runs, but the addFactiiis updates do not make it to the above component.
type Props = {
  updateAddFactiiis: (tag: FactiiiTag, updatedTag: FactiiiTag) => void;
};

const NewPostFactiii = (props: Props) => {

  const handleClick = async (tag: FactiiiTag) => {
    props.updateAddFactiiis(tag, updatedTag);
  };
}

